# BMS abnormal behavior

Tags: batteries, parallel, bms, 18650

I would like to power the lighting system of a small cabin using 3 DeWalt 18 V, 5 Ah battery packs. The system consists of six 10 W bulbs each (12/24 V) and a 20 W, 12 V spotlight.

DeWalt battery packs come with a charging PCB, but they do not have undervoltage protection. Therefore I opted to use a 5S BMS. The batteries are removable, the BMS is connected to the circuit and the batteries are removed / inserted upstream.

To connect the three battery packs in parallel I used 3 ideal diodes so as to be able to connect only 1 or 2 battery packs, or use batteries with different charge levels.

I tested the circuit but I encounter some problems:

1. With a single battery and the 3 BMS connected in parallel I detect a voltage of approximately 15 V between the upstream of the diodes D2 and D3 and the groud. This voltage drops to 5 V if I add a load to the ends of the diodes. (fig 1)
2. If I connect only one battery (2 BMS disconnected) with the load connected, the device sometimes does not supply current. To make it work I have to disconnect the battery and the load, wait 1 minute, insert the batteries and then reconnect the load. (fig 2)
3. If I do the same with all 3 BMS connected (all P- terminals of the BMS connected together) the result is similar but more likely it won't work.

I've attached an electrical diagram and information on the components used. Do you have any ideas or suggestions to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image: BMS]

Comment: I assume you are using old Dewalt battery packs?  It wouldn't make much economic sense to use new ones.

Comment: Please add the BMS datasheet to the question.

Comment: Yes the batteries are old. I purchased the BMS on aliexres, it is not branded and on each product page I find different information. This is one of the most complete:

Comment: https://it.aliexpress.com/item/1005006126670782.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000014.7.259fL2TZL2TZ7f&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.40000.326746.0&scm_id=1007.40000.326746.0&scm-url=1007.40000.326746.0&pvid=c8ed2aeb-cd2a-4f63-b1b7-f0643ee392ef&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.40000.326746.0,pvid:c8ed2aeb-cd2a-4f63-b1b7-f0643ee392ef,tpp_buckets:668%232846%238115%23851&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21EUR%219.72%213.01%21%21%2174.02%21%21%40210385bb16999149691528206e4688%2112000035875602800%21rec%21IT%21756424695%21

Comment: one last observation on the problem I forgot about: if I connect all three batteries there are no problems (the few times I tried everything went well)

Comment: Please add the BMS datasheet to the *question*.

Comment: If all the BMS datasheets are different, how do you know you have the right one?  BMS performs a critical safety function. I cannot recommend using the one you currently have.